# Check csv txt file for changes before importing, if change copy to new top row of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that I want to list the last 10 (most recent) songs played from a radio program I use.

The radio program updates a simple txt file with comma separated values of the one song that is currently playing.

The thing I'm hoping to achieve with my google script is to move the entire existing list in the google sheet down a row, clear anything after the 11th row, then paste the new song details into row number 2 (just below my header row).

The following draft script clears my sheet and imports the song info from the txt file.  It is set to run every minute.

The problem is firstly, I don't know what script is required to cut and paste rows in the existing sheet down one row.
Secondly, and more importantly, I only want this to happen if the song has indeed changed.  (additional note: is it possible to run script more frequently than every minute?)

*Here is my existing script.*

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:G");
 range.clearContent();

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("commaseparatedtxttest.txt").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

**Summary of questions:**

1.How to check if values in txt file have changed, and only continue if they have

2.How to move down existing data in sheet down one row before pasting new data into row two

3.How to run script automatically more frequently than 1minute (eg.10 secs)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Sorry, I misread it.
You can check whether the file has been updated within a minute. In that case insert a row after the first one, copy data from txt file to the second row and delete the 12th row. So until you reach 10 records it keeps storing songs and deleting a blank 12th row, after it adds the new record on the top and deletes the last one.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:G"); 
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("commaseparatedtxttest.txt").next();
      // If the difference between timestamp and file last updated date is less than 1 min 
  if (new Date() - file.getLastUpdated() <= 60 * 1000) {
    // insert row after header only if file has been edited
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(1, 1);
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    // Last 10 songs are stored between rows 2 and 11, so delete row 12
    sheet.deleteRow(12);
  }
}
```

According to [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) `.everyMinutes(n)` method is the lower.

Comment: Thanks,  I will try to copy and paste your suggestion.  I assume the //file last updated file relates to the txt file not the spreadsheet?

Comment: I like the file.getLastUpdated, seems to work a treat.  I understand from both answers that the minimum time for running a script is one minute.

Comment: if the script ran every minute, could I set the file.getLastUpdated to be only a couple of seconds earlier, or does it not really matter since the script only runs every minute?  (ie. what if the txt file had been updated just a few seconds before this script ran again).

Comment: Yes, the time difference is in milliseconds, so one minute is 60 * 1000. E.g. if you change it to 58 * 1000 the script will check for file changes within 58 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**How to check if values in txt file have changed, and only continue if they have**

Look into [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change). You can perform operations when onChange triggers.

**How to move down existing data in sheet down one row before pasting new data into row two**

For moving data in sheets you'll prolly going to use two major sheet methods like [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) to get data from a certain range. You'll also use [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

**How to run script automatically more frequently than 1minute (eg.10 secs)**

For this you'll be using [Time-drive triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) which is a form of Installable trigger. However since this has a limit of one trigger per hour, use [ClockTriggerBuilder everyMinutes(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into those.